# Adding image to layout

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to perform a simple (or I thought it was simple) operation.

I have some files in a folder, some of them are .pgn

I want to grab just the .png files and depending on the file show it on a GUI inside one or another layout.

To do so, I have this piece of code:

```
from PIL import Image

for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if f.endswith(".png"):
        if 'scatterPlot' in f:
            myImage = Image.open(f)
            mywidget = QtGui.QWidget(myImage )
            self.ui.horizontalLayout_scattUp.addWidget(mywidget )

        if 'histogram' in f:
            myImage = Image.open(f)
            mywidget = QtGui.QWidget(myImage)
            self.ui.horizontalLayout_histtUp.addWidget(mywidget)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      mywidget  = QtGui.QWidget(myImage)
TypeError: QWidget(QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'instance'
```

And I really do not know how to work around it.

I would like to know the correct way to grab an existing image and put it inside a GUI layout.

I am using python 2.7 on windows 7 with QtDesigner

Comment: What makes you think a `QWidget` takes a (PIL) image as argument? `QWidget` is a very general class, that takes a "parent" as (first) argument.

Comment: Hi Evert, nothing actually makes me think that, I tried some different ways and I coudn't get any results, so I just exposed here my last try. Of course it is not correct, as I am getting the traceback error

Comment: I no nothing about PyQT, but searching for "pyqt display image" shows some useful links. Have you explored those?

Comment: Im working on it right now